# Вывод из mysql по блочно

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо вывести с mysql статьи так, чтобы они чередовались по блокам. Чтобы через каждые 2 статьи - следующие 2 оборачивались блоком `<div class="row"></div>`

Вот картинка, как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня код такой:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles limit 10";
$result = mysql_query($query);                                      
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo '<div class="col-lg-6">'.$r['title'].'</div>'
}
```

Выводит подряд `<div class="col-lg-6">Заголовок</div>`, а нужно как на картинке каждые 2 статьи в блоке `<div class="row"></div>`.

Comment: прочитайте все в массив и при помощи array_chunk($arr,2) разбейте на пары.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чисто в целях обучения:

```
$i = 0;
echo '<div class="row">';
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    if ($i % 2 == 0 && $i != 0) {
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }
    echo '<div class="col-lg-6">' . $r['title'] . '</div>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Stop-TussiN не используйте драйвер mysql, даже в учебных целях. Учите сразу mysqli. Оно конечно всё похоже, но время потеряете. И маловероятно что вам залетят боевые задачи с mysql

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что MySQL тут не при чём. Вам надо сгруппировать данные из списка в списки по N элементов. Если вы освоите этот навык, то сможете применить его не только к этой задаче.

Допустим есть список от 1 до 10. Как его разбить на списки по 2? Может быть что-то есть в документации php? Может быть среди [функций для работы с массвами](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php) (всегда полезно заглянуть в документацию, не стесняйтесь делать это).

Ого, [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php)! Попробуем?
Наберите в консоли `php -a` (это интерактивный режим, где вы можете писать php-код и он будет сразу выполняться) и введите такие строки:

```
$list = range(1, 10);
$chunkedList = array_chunk($list, 2);
var_dump($chunkedList);
```

Бах! То что надо! (чтобы выйти из интерактивного режима нажмите `ctrl+c` или введите `exit` нажмите enter)

Теперь как это вывести в HTML? Очень просто -- два цикла:

```
<?php foreach ($chunkedList as $chunk): ?>
    <div>
        <?php foreach ($chunk as $item): ?>
            <div><?= $item ?></div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Примечание

Список строк можно получить так:

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Гляньте ещё про то, [как генерировать html в php](https://egorbanin.github.io/fs/templates.html). Надеюсь будет полезно.